# Python index error in BeautifulSoup script

Tags: python, dictionary, indexing, beautifulsoup, urllib3

I am writing a small Python scraping script that pulls some price data from a website using urllib3 library and parses this in the Beautiful Soup Library so I can find the appropriate class that holds the data I am interested in before inserting this into a list of dictionaries for me to use later on in my application.

I have one item I iterate through in the postcode list, and then for each (Key) in this item I create a string to build my URL for my http.request that is stored in the variable priceurl.
priceurl is then parsed through BeautifulSoup and stored in the soup variable.

I then do a findAll on the html class I am interested in within the soup variable and store the results in the links variable.
Finally I attempt to write the data I am interested in back to the postcode list, dictionary key, dictionary key.

I am having a problem running the below code on Heroku where I get the following error:

2017-08-25T01:14:34.311553+00:00 app[web.1]:     postcode[0][each]["price"] = links[2]
2017-08-25T01:14:34.311553+00:00 app[web.1]: IndexError: list index out of range

As far as I am able to tell from using the interactive interpreter and checking the lenth of the list it isn't out of range (however it obviously is!!). I am left scratching my head!!! Help Please!!!

```
realestateurl = "https://www.realestate.com.au/neighbourhoods/"
postcode = [{3192: {"price": "100", "suburb": "cheltenham"}, 3195: {"price": "200", "suburb": "mentone"},
             3193: {"price": "300","suburb""parkdale"}}]

for item in postcode:
    for each in item:
        priceurl = http.request("GET", realestateurl + item[each]["suburb"] + "-" + (str(each)) + "-vic",preload_content=False)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(priceurl)
        links = soup.findAll("div", {"class": "price strong"})
        postcode[0][each]["price"] = links[2]
```

Comment: Have you tried printing your `links` list before finding the third element? Perhaps there is an instance where the third element doesn't exit.

Comment: Note there is a missing colon in your `postcode`.

Comment: Thanks for your time. I did try printing the links as I went through the elements and I thought they looked good but I must have overlooked that they had the wrong postcodes in the links I was building. I appreciate your assistance.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is pretty much working fine. I used request module and BeautifulSoup in Python3 and I was able to get output as:

```
https://www.realestate.com.au/neighbourhoods/cheltenham-3192-vic
[<div class="price strong">$905,000</div>, <div class="price strong">$975,500</div>, <div class="price strong">$1,171,500</div>, <div class="price strong">$400 PW</div>, <div class="price strong">$500 PW</div>, <div class="price strong">$655 PW</div>, <div class="price strong">$382,550</div>, <div class="price strong">$528,000</div>, <div class="price strong">$745,000</div>, <div class="price strong">$330 PW</div>, <div class="price strong">$380 PW</div>, <div class="price strong">$550 PW</div>, <div class="price strong"></div>, <div class="price strong"></div>, <div class="price strong"></div>]
https://www.realestate.com.au/neighbourhoods/parkdale-3193-vic
[]
```

Now notice that for first link the output is pretty much acceptable but for second it is showing nothing. May be because of this you are getting error.

If you will open that link in browser then you will notice that it will give 404 error. So either your data inside postcode is wrong or you might need to do some error handling.

Try using try and except and note down those links which are not working. For example

https://www.realestate.com.au/neighbourhoods/mentone-3195-vic

This link is also giving 404 error.

Comment: Thanks for your time. This was indeed the problem.